# Is there an out-of-the-box way to configure spring security matchers from external file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

What I want is a way to configure **antMatchers** in **HttpSecurity** via external file in easy-to-understand format (so it can be edited by someone who knows nothing about app). Only the **matchers** (!) part.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/some/url").hasRole("ROLE01")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/some/other/url").hasRole("ROLE02")
            .antMatchers("/some/public-urls/*").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().denyAll();
}
```

I know that you can set up a bean via xml, but this is not the most intuitive format for the unfamiliar person.

The only option I see now is to make my own file in custom format, read it on startup and use it to configure HttpSecurity. But this turns out to be a reinvention of the wheel.

So, maybe I'm missing something and there is some other way available out of the box or de facto some standard to solve this problem?